# How to match this string patteren?

Tags: java, regex

Below is my string.

```
{" 3/4", "ERW", "A53-A", "STEEL", "PIPE", "STD", "BLK", "PE"}
```

i need to match this string using regular expression, please help me to achieve this.

I tried below code snippet to achieve this, but it is matching partially(only 6 strings i can match using this).

```
String pattern = "\\s*,\\s*";
String[] sourceValues= listTwo.get(1).toString().split(pattern);
```

i cant able to match first and last string using this pattern.

Please help me to achieve this, i need to match all 8 strings.

Thanks, 
Sandesh P

Comment: Do mention, what is the output you expect

Comment: please refer the below link for details of expected output https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48882295/how-to-consider-entire-string-array-with-regular-expression

Comment: `String input = "{\" 3/4\", \"ERW\", \"A53-A\", \"STEEL\", \"PIPE\", \"STD\", \"BLK\", \"PE\"}";
  String pattern = "\\s*,\\s*";
  String[] sourceValues = input.split(pattern);
  System.out.println(Arrays.asList(sourceValues));`


Output: `[{" 3/4", "ERW", "A53-A", "STEEL", "PIPE", "STD", "BLK", "PE"}]`.
As far as i see, all strings are matched

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try:

[`" ?([^"]+)"`](https://regex101.com/r/vWg7zg/1)

That would capture what is between double quotes (without a leading single whitespace) in group 1. Now you have 8 strings instead of 6.

```
List<String> allMatches = new ArrayList<String>();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\" ?([^\"]+)\"").matcher("{\" 3/4\", \"ERW\", \"A53-A\", \"STEEL\", \"PIPE\", \"STD\", \"BLK\", \"PE\"}");
while (m.find()) {
    allMatches.add(m.group(1));
}
```

[Java output test](http://rextester.com/VZSC1029)